# Active Reports 9: Multi-Colum SectionReport, is this possible?

Tags: c#, report, activereports

I'm trying to get a SectionReport to have more than one column. The report is very long and there is plenty of space on the right side of the list (see upload)
How can I do that in Visual Studio 13 (C#) using Active Reports 9? The data comes from a json (content is dynamic)

Thank you :)[image: Report]

(Sorry, I had to blur it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try ColumnCount and ColumnDirection properties on the detail section
http://www.programering.com/a/MDNxQDMwATg.html